# How do I sort my ArrayList in alphabetical order and have it used with a setText method?

Tags: java, netbeans, arraylist

This is what I have

```
ArrayList <String> cdList = new ArrayList();
Collections.addAll(cdList, "ExampleA\n"+"ExampleB\n"+"ExampleC\n"+"ExampleD");

Collections.sort(cdList, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);

System.out.println(cdList);


    bigBox.setText("Original Order\n**************\n");


    for (int i = 0; i < cdList.size(); i++)  {
    bigBox.setText(bigBox.getText()+""+cdList.get(i)+"\n");
    }

    bigBox.setText(bigBox.getText()+"\n\nSorted Order\n************\n");
    Collections.sort(cdList);


    for (int j = 0; j < cdList.size(); j++)  {
    bigBox.setText(bigBox.getText()+""+);
    }
```

I want the 4 examples outputted in their original order, and in alphabetical order. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are adding only one element (String) to the list, a concatenated string.

Change this

```
ArrayList <String> cdList = new ArrayList();
Collections.addAll(cdList, "ExampleA\n"+"ExampleB\n"+"ExampleC\n"+"ExampleD");
```

to

```
List <String> cdList = new ArrayList<String>();
Collections.addAll(cdList, "ExampleA","ExampleB","ExampleC","ExampleD");
```

Read more [Collections#addAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection,%20T...%29)

And for showing you should use [append](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append%28java.lang.String%29) rather than `setText`.

Example:

```
bigBox.append("Original Order\n**************\n");
for (String s : cdList)  {
 bigBox.append(s);
 bigBox.append("\n");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, now if you look at the bottom, it says bixBog.setText(bigBox.getText()+""+);, what do I do if I want the sorted order in there?

Comment: @user2984158 don't know what type is it `bigBox` if it has an append method use that, if not you can create a `StringBuilder` and `append` the partial results then you call `setText(stringBuilder.toString())`. Let me know if you have difficult doing this!

Comment: Oh i's a JTextArea, I'm sorry I'm not very good at programming

Comment: How do I make a StringBuilder and do all that stuff you said? I'm very new at programming and it's for an online course so my teacher doesn't explain hardly anything

Comment: @user2984158 if it's a textArea you can use [append](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append(java.lang.String)) method

Comment: Sorry for being so uneducated. How do I use the append method with the code I currently have?

Comment: @user2984158 check the answer , `append` append text to the end of the text, and `setText` set a new text

Comment: Okay cool, it's working for the original order, now how do I do it for the alphabetical order?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your elements are meant to be the strings `"ExampleA"`, `"ExampleB"`, `"ExampleC"`, and `"ExampleD"`. If the is the case, what you are currently doing in your call to `Collections.addAll()` is adding them to cdList as **one long string**. the `+` operator, when used on strings, appends them. What you probably want it to separate them with commas, so that instead of having:

```
Collections.addAll(cdList, "ExampleA\n"+"ExampleB\n"+"ExampleC\n"+"ExampleD");
```

you have:

```
Collections.addAll(cdList, "ExampleA\n", "ExampleB\n", "ExampleC\n", "ExampleD");
```